# error: cannot call member function impl() of impl_pointer in boost

Tags: c++, boost, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to build a version of Caffe for object detection called [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd)

I checked out the code and I am getting the error `cannot call member function ‘boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::impl_pointer boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::impl()` which seems to be related to boost library and I have installed boost as a dependency:

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/detail/seq_index_node.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::increment(boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>*&) [with Super = boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::null_augment_policy, boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > >]’:
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/detail/bidir_node_iterator.hpp:55:16:   required from ‘boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<Node>& boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<Node>::operator++() [with Node = boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::null_augment_policy, boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp:269:73:   required from ‘boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Value, IndexSpecifierList, Allocator>::multi_index_container(const boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Value, IndexSpecifierList, Allocator>&) [with Value = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; IndexSpecifierList = boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>; Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:191:94:   required from ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::basic_ptree(const boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>&) [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Data = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; KeyCompare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
src/caffe/layers/detection_output_layer.cu:220:29:   required from ‘void caffe::DetectionOutputLayer<Dtype>::Forward_gpu(const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&, const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&) [with Dtype = float]’
src/caffe/layers/detection_output_layer.cu:302:147:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/detail/seq_index_node.hpp:198:23: error: cannot call member function ‘boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::impl_pointer boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::impl() [with Super = boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::null_augment_policy, boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > >; boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<Super>::impl_pointer = boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node_impl<std::allocator<char> >*]’ without object
     impl_pointer xi=x->impl();
                   ~~~~^~
```

Any thoughts how to rectify that?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I had the same issue recently on Ubuntu 18.10 with boost 1.67 an CUDA 10.1. I fixed the error by switching to CUDA 9.2. and gcc-7. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not the best solution, but I solved this problem by enabling CPU_ONLY mode in the Makefile.config

Comment: Thanks Museus. But I would like to use GPU to have maximum speed on Caffe